# MySQLi PHP result array incompatibility?

Tags: php, html, sql, image, mysqli

I was working on a project and had the following snippet inside my code:

```
<div id= "searchresults" style="min-height: 10vh; height: auto; background-color:white; display: block;">
<?php
//Makes connection
include 'dxbase.php';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST["search"])){
$tempvardf = '%'.$_POST['search'].'%'; #############
//Defines SQL command to bring up data about the products matching the set search
$sql = "SELECT id, name, price, location FROM products WHERE name LIKE ?;"; #'%$_POST[search]%'
//Create a prepared statement
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
//Prepare the prepared statement
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "SQL STATEMENT FAILED... OOF";
} else {
    //Bind paramaters to placeholder
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $tempvardf);
    //Run paramaters inside database
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['name']. "<br>";
        if(isset($row['path'])){
        echo "<img src=". $row['path'].">";
        } else {
            echo "can't access image path";
        }
    }
    echo "And that's it!";
}



} else {

}


?>
</div>
```

When I search, the names of products in the database come up but when I try and echo the images, it tells me it can't access the image path.

The image path is in the database as is shown here Evidence:
[image: Evidence], however, so I was wondering what was wrong and why they weren't displaying... As shown here:
[image: As shown here]

Despite my best attempts and hours of research, I'm still stuck...

Answer (score 1):

Where do you select the path of your image in the Select statement? There is no field 'path' in your $result.